# Will adding "" to database value change it to a string if it was a Null?

Tags: string, vb6, null

If I am retrieving a value from a database which could be `Null`, will adding a `""` to the value avoid the problem of the value potentially being `Null`?

```
Dim strFinal as String
strFinal = rsCustomers("Suburb") & ""
```

If `rsCustomers("Suburb")` happens to be `Null`, will the adding of `""` to it cause the result to be a string?

I am looking at someone else's code and I am just trying to understand why there is the continual use of this pattern.

Comment: Couldn't you know ... try it, and see?

Comment: @Brian: I am experimenting with it but it is very useful to get a community opinion at the same time.

Comment: I wouldn't use such a pattern blindly.  Null has a specific meaning distinct from a 0-length String.

Comment: @BobRiemersma: what would be the problem with it?

Comment: You will no longer be able to distinguish between "no value" and "zero-length value."  There's a lengthy discussion at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: @BobRiemersma: but all I want to do is produce a string and make it empty if the database value is Null. Seems quite a smart way to do that.

Comment: But my point was "don't do this blindly."  If your database has Null values they are either there for a serious reason or you screwed up.  If they are intentional, then doing something like this is fine if you know you want to convert Null to "" *intentionally* in a particular place.  So doing this can be fine where it makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found exactly your question here [Two handy functions for Null handling](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18325) in "Tip of the Day"

> You're probably aware that most VB functions don't work well with Null
>   values, which is an issue when you're working with database columns
>   that can accept Nulls. For example, the following statement:

```
Dim s as String
s = rs.Fields("AnyField")
```

> can raise error 94 "Invalid use of Null". **The usual workaround is to
>   force the conversion to string by appending an empty string, as in**:

```
s = rs.Fields("AnyField") & ""
```

> However, this solution slightly affect code readability, especially
>   if other people in your team **aren't aware of the trick**

Comment: +1 Any VB6 answer linking to an article by Franceso Balena must be correct! CraigJ, you could do worse than read [his book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Microsoft-Visual-Basic-6-0/dp/0735605580/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpt_4)